# How to customize Y-Axis label in Chart.js with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, charts, echarts, vue-chartjs

I saw many solutions in Stackoverflow but no one is solving my problem.

I want to change the scale of my y axis values.

It will be

0
100
200
300

[image]

My Code:

```
yAxis: [{
          type: 'value',
          axisTick: {
            show: false
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                stepSize: 100,
                min: 0,
                max: 300
              }
            }]
          },
          axisLabel: {//},
        }],
        series: [{
          //
          lineStyle: {//},
          areaStyle: {
            normal: {
              //
          },
     itemStyle: {
       normal: {
         //
    }
  },
  data: [236, 0]
}]
```

I have changed this also.

```
axisTick: {
    show: false
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use [this live example](https://jsfiddle.net/k8y01erL/) to compare your settings with the example's working settings.

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [236, 0],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 300,
          stepSize: 100,
          reverse: false,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To customize lebels you can use this`var chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: data, options: { scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { min: 0, max: 300, stepSize: 100, reverse: false, callback: function(value, index, values) { return '$' + value; } } }] } } });`